# Failed to load because no supported source was found - only on apple OS devices, on every browser, and only when played from within the web app

Tags: ios, angular, video

weird, persistent problem with playing videos on my web application.

recently I started getting "MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED" only on mac and ios for every video on my site.
i'm using a custom video player that's based on html5's native video element. the video itself is hosted on a cdn.
stuff I've tried:

1. navigating directly to the source link - works. so it's not a problem with the file itself.
2. embedding the source link within a different, single page web app - works. so it's not the cdn's fault.
3. disabling my 'custom' web played into a regular web player (saw in another forum post that apple doesn't allow for custom players) - doesn't work. i get a blank image with a crossed play button.

no errors pop up when i play the video from code. MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED and Failed to load because no supported source was found are the only errors i get.

something to note - since i don't own a mac, i don't have access to any developer tools, and since it happens only on ios devices, the only way i've managed to debug so far is by printing the console logs onto some div. i'm not sure i capture everything that way, but i haven't had time to mess around with other ways to access dev tools. i did check a friend's mac, and was able to read the "Failed to load because no supported source was found" exception

i will say that recently my auth0 page returned an "unable to configure verification page" error on ios devices, which went away when i allowed cross website tracking, so i suspect it's something with apple having more restrictions.

anyway, i'm stumped. been tackling this issue for a few hours.